# Has anybody used AspectMap?

Tags: aop, structuremap, aspect-ratio

I have just stumbled accross the following AOP framework built on top of StructureMap and was wondering if anybody has any experience using it.

Any good, any issues?

http://www.chrissurfleet.co.uk/post/2012/06/27/AspectMap-Part-5-Aspect-Nesting-and-Prioritising.aspx

Or can you suggest any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I use it, and like it, but then I built it! Its nice and easy to get started with, but isn't as full featured as some of the alternatives.

The nice thing is though that the code you write is generally reusable - so if you decide you want to use something else it will be easy to swap the aop provider out. Or you can easily start with something else and move onto AspectMap ;)

If you've got any questions feel free to mail me via the blog, or just ask on here